# Apply Spring formatter to non-form text in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC 3, I have a customer `Formatter` that converts my entity objects to text and parses the text for my entity objects. It's registered with the `conversionService` bean. This link shows how it works: http://springinpractice.com/2012/01/07/making-formselect-work-nicely-using-spring-3-formatters/

I'm wondering if there's any way to apply the formatter to text not inside of forms. Specifically, I'd like my object displays to have a web link to their foreign key entities with the same text that's used in the forms. I've gotten the forms to display successfully, but I haven't been able to apply it to the text on the JSP page. Instead, it uses `toString`.

I've played around with `<spring:bind>`, `<spring:message>`, and `<spring:eval>`, but they don't seem to apply to the formatter. `<spring:eval>` attempts to use the `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this helps someone else looking for this. It turns out it was `<spring:eval>`, which makes sense, since somehow it has to be linked to Spring. The issue was syntactical. The statement below causes the entity to be processed by a Spring converter.

```
<spring:eval expression="myEntityObject" htmlEscape="false"/>
```

No JSP tags are needed, like: `${ok}`

This uses the Spring expression language.